# Pre-Pre-build Steps in Hudson

Tags: maven-2, hudson, clearcase

I'm in a bit of a pickle. I'm trying to run some environmental scripts before I run the build in a m2 project, but it seems no matter how hard I try - the 'pre' build script are never run early enough.

Before the 'pre-build' scripts are run, the project checks to see if the correct files are in the workspace - files that won't be there until the scripts I've written are executed.

To make them 'pre-build', I'm using the [M2 Extra Steps](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/M2+Extra+Steps+Plugin) plugin - but's it's not 'pre' enough.

Has anyone got any suggestions as to how I can carry out what I want to do?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem stemmed from the fact I wanted to set-up my workspace before I ran anything due to an issue with Dynamic Views (ClearCase) not being accessible from the workspace - I wanted to add a symlink to fix this.

However, Andrew Bayer has made a change to the plugin that I'm currently testing that should fix this...so the question is probably invalid in it's current form.

Will edit it once we come to a conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered breaking it up into two projects, and setting the pre-build project to be upstream of the build project?

e.g.,
Foo Pre-build
Foo Build

After Foo Pre-build runs, cause "Foo Build" to run.

I have used this, admittedly in different scenarios than yours, quite successfully. This has the added benefit (if you need it) of allowing you to manually run a build without going through the pre-build steps, if you know they aren't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the free form project type and not the maven project type.

If this is a problem (ie, there are projects that are expecting to be triggered by or triggering from), consider using a custom workspace location and having a free form project execute in this workspace before the maven project runs. The free form project can be used as the trigger for the maven project.

Answer (score 0):

Does adding another build step as a shell script work?

Comment: Not really, it's an m2project rather than a free-style one - so the only way I can have pre-build setup scripts is to use the plugin mentioned above. It's just not pre 'enough' :(